# Vamos desclassificar a tag [class]

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags, tag-específica

Recentemente me deparei com a tag [class](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class).

Atualmente esta tag possui 12 perguntas, e não apresenta nenhum tipo de descrição wiki. A meu ver em nenhuma destas perguntas esta tag trás qualquer benefício. A razão disso é que uma vez que o termo "*class*" tem uma miríade de significados diferentes de acordo com o contexto empregado e cada uma dessas questões têm um contexto diferente, o resultado é que essas questões se referem cada qual a uma coisa distinta das demais chamada "*class*".

Essas perguntas, apesar de tratarem de assuntos bem diferentes e sem relação entre si, exceto a coincidência casual da terminologia de alguma coisa chamada "*class*", acabam por ser colocadas todas com uma mesma tag em comum, sendo que na verdade elas não têm nada em comum na prática. Desta forma, esta tag acaba não servindo para prover nenhum tipo de organização de informação, muito pelo contrário, ela acaba desorganizando informação.

A minha sugestão é simplesmente colocar esta tag em uma lista negra.

Comment: +1 Concordo. Temos que acabar com essas tags que só fazem ruído.

Comment: Concordo também, força nisso!

Comment: `+1` - concordo também.

Comment: Só faltou a criação traduzida da tag `burninate-request`:P

Comment: Eu acho que precisa tirar de onde ela não faz sentido e criar sinônimo onde ela faz.

Comment: Merecia um `-1` por um texto super confuso, e por não ter escrito *"Vamos des[class]ificar a tag"* - mas, infelizmente, você tem razão... ;)

Comment: @DanielGomes Downvote por desperdiçar uma oportunidade de trocadilho devia ser regra do site!

Comment: @DanielGomes Eu pensei em escrever o título dessa forma, mas achei que ficaria muito estranho. Mas deixando o título de lado, o que exatamente você achou "*super confuso*" no meu texto?

Comment: Nada demais - você se repetiu algumas vezes, e *enrolou* para dizer que `class` é genérica demais para ser útil. De qualquer modo, a mensagem foi passada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu concordo que ela *poderia* ser corretamente usada, mas não consigo pensar num exemplo em que ela agrega em alguma coisa.

Há pelo menos duas objeções atualmente:

1. Praticamente todas as questões com essa tag atualmente não fazem bom uso dela
2. O termo é genérico demais e pode ser facilmente confundido entre classes de CSS, arquivos `.class` do Java ou efetivamente classes da teoria de orientação a objetos. Acredito que tags mais específicas são preferíveis. De qualquer forma, já temos a tag [classes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/classes) para dar conta do último caso.

## Update

Verifiquei todas as questões com esta tag. Somente em duas faziam algum sentido.

Então editei as demais perguntas, removendo a tag. Depois mesclei a tag com [classes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/classes).

Comment: Concordo totalmente, o problema de confundir com class do css e já temos a tag classes mostra realmente que a tag dificilmente será "util". +1 Até editei algumas perguntas. Amanhã edito mais se ainda houver alguma

Answer (score 0):

**Eu discordo**.

### Quanto a sua posição

Esta correto em sua analise sobre a tag, concordo com ela.

### Problema

- A tag não é auto suficiente, ela tem muitos intuitos, como já abordaste.
  Diferente de uma tag como [jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), pois todos entendem que se está falando especificamente de [jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) ou [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php).
- O mal uso das tag. É comum ver perguntas que estão com a tag incorreta ou at[e mesmo faltando, o que deve ser feito é corrigir.

### Defendendo minha posição

Ao meu ver as tags auxiliam para especificar os recursos envolvidos, desta forma quanto mais tags melhor, mas como disse o problema é o mal uso.

### Quanto a pesquisa pela tag

Como disse, ela não é auto suficiente. Desta forma, o erro não está na tag e sim em quem pesquisa, pois não está sendo específico o suficiente no que deseja.

### Sobre a wiki

Teria que se gerar um explicação genérica, pois ela está presente em vários contextos.

Comment: Acabei de ver que no SOen, `class` foi discutida, e mantida, faz alguns meses. Interessante! Eu, pessoalmente, penso que ela é muito fácil de ser *mal* utilizada.