# StackOverflow - Uma Sociedade

Tags: debate

## Previamente algumas definições

### Sociedade

> Uma sociedade é o conjunto de pessoas que compartilham propósitos, gostos, preocupações e costumes, e que interagem entre si constituindo uma comunidade.
>   É um grupo de indivíduos que formam um sistema semi-aberto, no qual a maior parte das interações é feita com outros indivíduos pertencentes ao mesmo grupo. Uma sociedade é uma rede de relacionamentos entre pessoas. [(wiki)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociedade)

### Política

> Nos regimes democráticos, a ciência política é a atividade dos cidadãos que se ocupam dos assuntos públicos com seu voto ou com sua militância. Organizações cujas estruturas e processos de ação se aproximem de um governo, em complexidade e interconexão. [(wiki)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica),[(wiki)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ci%C3%AAncia_pol%C3%ADtica)

## StackOverflow (Baseado em minha opinião e análises)

### Objetivo

O StackOverflow é uma sociedade, na qual as pessoas tem como objetivo **ajudar** e buscar **ajuda**.

### União

Quando você entra nesta grande e formidável sociedade, você tem um intuito que pode variar entre, ajudar, solicitar ajuda ou, o que ocorre na maioria das vezes, os dois.

### Deveres

Contudo, como toda sociedade, se tem regras e se deve segui-las. Aí que entra a parte da política, pois até mesmo aqui nesta comunidade você é um cidadão, um indivíduo que tem o direito de opinar, sugerir e votar. Haverão regras que você pode não gostar ou achar arcaicas, contudo a maioria votou por elas e caso você as quebre deve estar ciente que ocorreram consequências.
Mas como se pode haver regras se não votamos em nenhuma regra? A equipe do StackOverflow define as regras básicas que podem ser encontradas na [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help), contudo o resto é por conta da comunidade, e ocorre aqui mesmo no Meta, com [proposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4469/vamos-desclassificar-a-tag-class) e [debates](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debate), então fique ligado e tente ler o máximo possível, e opinar.

### Ganhos

Muito conhecimento, grandes amizades, caráter, respeito:

- Conhecimento: Quando você pergunta e recebe respostas, está automaticamente ganhando conhecimento por aprender algo novo. Já quando você responde e ganha votos a favor você tem a afirmação de que seu pensamento esta correto e adquiriu conhecimento.
- Amizades: Eu recomendo a participação no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha). Lá se discute indiretamente, sobre os mais diversos assuntos, se brinca e se expõem ideias. Aquela pergunta que você não sabe se faz, pois pode parecer bobo, passe lá que alguém podem se ajudar, ou até mesmo recomendar que seja feita.
- Caráter: Pode parecer estranho, mas sim o stack ajuda a formar seu caráter, mediante situações de respeito, ajuda e críticas, tanto as construtivas quantos as pejorativas, pois te ajudam a melhorar.
- Respeito: Isso acho que deve ocorrer a todo momento não apenas aqui, pois se deve respeitar as decisões dos outros assim como os diferentes níveis de conhecimento, tente se pôr no lugar do outro e analisar a situação.

### Problemas

Como toda sociedade, esta também não é perfeita. Afinal, ela é feita de pessoas. Há problemas, muitos de longa data, o que você pode fazer quando se deparar com um deles é primeiramente [ter calma](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4407/%C3%89-preciso-ter-calma-refletir-em-caso-de-d%C3%BAvida-e-se-n%C3%A3o-souber-n%C3%A3o-ir-com-o-reb). Pode nem ser um problema, apenas algo que do seu ponto de vista é um problema, então antes de sair fazendo qualquer coisa que você possa se arrepender depois, pense e pergunte (de preferência no chat, após isso no meta).

## Algumas questões

Gostaria de me manifestar a respeito sobre algumas peculiaridades:
[Eu já fiz isso uma vez](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4285/stack-overflow-perfil-de-pergunta), alguns quesitos eu ainda mantenho outros eu já mudei, é o que chamamos de aperfeiçoamento.

### Perguntas

Eu já mudei um pouco meus critérios de pergunta, e isso se deve justamente pela participação na comunidade.
Pelo que notei a comunidade aceita praticamente todo o tipo de pergunta, exceto claro as que fogem as [regras básicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), e realmente isso é bom pois abrange um público muito grande.
Atualmente, quando a pergunta não é muito do meu agrado, pois foi mal formulada ou não tem clareza o suficiente, eu tento me por no lugar do autos (AP), e imaginar alguma situações, como conhecimento, pressa, lógica, etc. Então dependendo das situações eu ajudo ou simplesmente ignoro, creio que dar downvote (falarei disso depois) seja muito pesado, simplesmente porque eu "não fui com a cara da pergunta".
Isto foi discutido no chat esta semana mesmo, seja bem:
[Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95543/gera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-boletos/95545) estava com `-2`.

[@CiganoMorrisonMendez](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2999/cigano-morrison-mendez) (C)
[@OnoSendai](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1897/onosendai) (O)

> C - "A galera já vai negativando, mas não entende que o autor da pergunta quer entender o básico do básico, que nenhum site tem."
>   C - "Isso aí mostra que a turma não anda pensando fora da caixa. É fácil negativar. Difícil é se colocar no lugar do outro."
>   O - "Acho que o povo esquece como no início era difícil até mesmo formular uma questão coerente se você não sabe dar nome aos bois."
>   C - "Ninguém nasce sabendo como gera boleto, o que é número de carteira, de convênio e de contrato. Tudo o que eu coloquei na resposta ali foram coisas que penei pra descobrir em algum momento."

(Me aproveitei da discussão no chat)

Creio que este é um caso que deve ser tomado como exemplo.

### Downvote

> "Com grandes poderes vem grandes responsabilidades"

Cuidado, atualmente isto na comunidade é uma arma bem poderosa, não fique usando simplesmente porque você pode.
São muitos os casos aqui em que ao dar um downvote a pessoa fica com raiva e sai retribuindo sem mesmo fazer sentido, então antes de usar este "poder", tente ser amigável e se por no lugar da pessoa, se cordial e tentar esclarecer e ajudar, caso ela se mostre indiferente então aplique o downvote.
As pesquisas que mostram que as pessoas ligam mais para um crítica do que para um elogio, [este](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4495/voc%C3%AA-n%C3%A3o-vai-com-a-minha-cara) é um exemplo.

#### Critérios

A dica que tenho para dar um downvote, é formar critérios (afinal somos programadores):

- Resposta igual: Eu já comentei isso com @WallaceMaxters, se algum da uma resposta exata igual a minha ou que seja 90% igual, eu uso o critérios de 20min, para verificar se é uma cópia de minha resposta, verificando o tempo em que postei e o tempo em que a pessoa respondeu, caso seja inferior, caraterizo por "pensamento similar".
- Perguntas: Sempre tento me pôr no lugar da pessoa e aí, dependendo da análise aplico o downvote.

### Opinião

Devemos lembrar que o Stack é formado por pessoas, pessoas das mais diversas idades, pensamentos e culturas, desta forma devemos entender e respeitar a opinião dos outros, não simplesmente impor nosso pensamento. Assim como nossos problemas de programação podem ter múltiplas respostas e meios de se fazer, devemos aceitar os meios dos demais, e caso não concorde, argumentar e explicar dando embasamento a sua críticas.
Devemos respeitar os diferentes níveis intelectuais e culturais de nossa sociedade.

## Concluindo

Creio que o site StackOverflow é um ótimo site, para aprendizado e criar amizades, sempre o recomendo para outros programadores, a comunidade é sempre muito receptiva e tem muito a oferecer para a construção das pessoas, não apenas profissionalmente, mas também ao caráter, basta que se queira participar.

## Propósito

O que quero com expor com todo este texto? Conscientização, como foi dito no chat. Creio que as pessoas simplesmente não estão sabendo respeitar as diversas opiniões. Como o próprio @CiganoMorrisonMendez disse: "É fácil negativar. Difícil é se colocar no lugar do outro."

Alguns usuários leem o meta, mas não participam do chat, no qual muito disto é discutido (em tempo real).

Comment: Obs.: eu ainda vou adicionar mais coisas.

Comment: Eu apenas não entendi o proposito exato deste "tópico", é uma campanha?

Comment: TL;DR : you're using it wrong... :(

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento digamos que pode ser sim uma campanha = D

Comment: @brasofilo Sorry friendy, I am learning = D

Comment: Lembrei que o tldr já foi discutido aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1641/201

Comment: É uma ótima análise. Felizmente, alguns que tinham a mentalidade de aplicar as regras "ideais" do site a ferro e fogo estão menos presentes, e a sociedade se torna cada vez mais tolerante e receptiva com novos usuários.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## O problema dos usuários inexperientes

Bem que todos sabem que o StackOverflow tem seus problemas, isso não é nenhuma novidade. No entanto, o problema mais grave é algo que os usuários mais experientes têm dificuldade em enxergar. Ocorre que nós que somos os usuários mais ativos e participantes do site, muitas vezes nos esquecemos que há um grande viés no nosso ponto de vista. A opinião dos usuários de pouca experiência dificilmente se faz ser ouvida.

No entanto, a verdade é que para os usuários iniciantes que venham fazer perguntas aqui, o StackOverflow tem a aparência de uma comunidade hostil e arrogante. Para nós que somos usuários com alta reputação, o StackOverflow parece ser algo muito democrático. Para quem é um usuário de baixa reputação no site, o StackOverflow é uma entidade totalitária. Veja esses links abaixo, são referentes ao StackOverflow em inglês, mas não devemos deixar que o mesmo tipo de problema venha afetar o nosso em português:

1. http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/741.php
2. https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.tygjlo9e0
3. http://michael.richter.name/blogs/awhy-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow
4. https://goofygrin.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/why-stackoverflow-sucks-and-participating-there-is-impossible/
5. http://www.borngeek.com/2012/01/04/stack-overflow-hates-new-users/

A vida para os iniciantes aqui do StackOverflow é difícil, e grande parte dos usuários que vem aqui e fazem alguma pergunta pela primeira vez, acabam sendo mal-recebidos com downvotes e acabam tendo as suas questões fechadas. O resultado é que eles vão embora para nunca mais voltar.

Quando você é um usuário novo que não conhece as regras do StackOverflow (e muitas vezes nem mesmo percebe isso) e pensa em postar uma pergunta ou resposta, é incerto se você vai ser bem recebido ou não, e muitas vezes você não é. Para quem é iniciante, e postou uma pergunta que na cabeça dele é ótimo, ter a sua pergunta fechada de forma súbita é algo muito frustrante. Receber downvotes também é muito frustrante, especialmente quando você recebe mais do que um.

Ok, mas o que fazer?

A resposta é orientar os novos usuários. Dar downvotes ou close-votes sem maiores explicações apenas gera frustração e raiva.

## Como um usuário iniciante se comporta?

Os novos usuários não entendem que nesse site não se pode fazer perguntas opinativas ou de escopo aberto. Aliás, os novos usuários muitas vezes nem sequer sabem dizer se as suas perguntas são opinativas ou de escopo aberto, e mesmo quando sabem, não são capazes de enxergar nenhum problema nisso. Se um novo usuário vem e posta uma pergunta do tipo "*Qual é melhor, Java ou PHP?*", é porque muitas vezes ele imagina que a resposta seja simplesmente e sempre "*Java é melhor sempre, ponto final*" ou sempre "*PHP é melhor sempre, ponto final*". Ele nem sequer sonha com a possibilidade de que isso dependa da opinião de quem está respondendo, do propósito para o qual ele quer desenvolver alguma coisa ou de um monte de outras circunstâncias. Ele realmente acredita do fundo de seu coração que a sua pergunta é uma ótima pergunta e que este é o melhor site para ela. Até ter a surpresa de ver a sua pergunta fechada com uma pontuação de -13.

[Aqui está um exemplo de uma pergunta dessas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95480/132), embora ela tenha escapado de ter um score bastante negativo:

> ### Qual a linguagem mais utilizada atualmente para criação de sites, blogs e e-commerce?
>
> Sempre fico fuçando nos códigos html e css, tenho um blog e ai vivo mexendo aqui e ali, no orkut eu criava vários recadinhos com html, finalmente descobri que gosto de fazer isso, pois parece ser meu hobby (kkk), claro as vezes fico irritada porque as coisas não sai como eu quero, então resolvi fazer um curso de web designer, porém estou em duvida pois pesquisei varias escolas e quero saber qual a linguagem mais atual usada, alguém recomenda uma escola?
>
> [web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web)

Se a pergunta realmente é ruim, deve-se fechá-la de fato. Entretanto, nós que somos usuários avançados temos a obrigação de orientar o usuário, pois "*com grandes poderes vem grandes responsabilidades*". No caso acima do Java vs PHP, não custa postar um comentário explicando que essa é uma pergunta que depende da opinião de cada um e que tem uma forte tendência a gerar uma discussão interminável e não produtiva e que esta não é a finalidade do site. Quando isso acontece, esse usuário quase sempre compreende isso e até agradece. Se a pergunta dele é fechada e negativada sem maiores explicações, ele apenas vai embora frustrado e revoltado e não volta nunca mais. Perguntas fechadas com pontuação zero são deletadas automaticamente com o tempo, então eu não dou downvote para não causar frustração no usuário.

Outra coisa que acontece é que o usuário inexperiente não sabe se expressar direito, não conhece os termos técnicos, não sabe como a linguagem de programação que está usando funciona e muitas vezes nem mesmo sabe o que ele quer tentar fazer. Por vezes ele aprende termos técnicos errados ou acaba inventando os seus. Posso citar um exemplo que já vi de alguém perguntando como se fazia para ter ["strings tridimensionais"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49276/132), sendo que no fim das contas o que ele queria era matrizes de strings.

Se expressar direito é importante e muitos novatos não sabem fazer isso. Há gente por aí que embora esteja tentando aprender a programar ou mesmo já esteja fazendo como profissão, simplesmente não conhece a língua portuguesa direito, escreve como se estivesse no chat do facebook e consegue tirar nota próxima de zero em quase qualquer redação que se disponha a fazer. Esse tipo de usuário também precisa de orientação, e esperar que ele poste boas perguntas sem ter prática é simplesmente uma coisa irreal e utópica. Se não formos complacentes e não tivermos uma postura orientadora, fatalmente teremos usuários a menos.

Exemplo de pergunta aonde o usuário iniciante não conseguiu se expressar direito e usou um português muito ruim (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/53928/1):

> ### bug na logica do php
>
> Bom estava eu desenvolvendo um chat em php+mysql só que estou com um problema na logica, ex: o usuario entra com o nickname ele adiciona no bd nicknametall,online , a pessoa vai e quer conversa com um usuario em reservado até ai ok, vamos supor:victor e carla, na tabela CONVERSA temos campo (de,para,msg) vai ficar fazendo a consulta de tempo em tempo por exemplo no victor consultaria { select de,msg from CONVERSA where para = victor; } + o problema em minha logica como exibiria as msg em ordem ? gostaria de uma logica exata de como funcionaria um chat... obrigado pessoal.
>
> [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)

Quando na pergunta estiverem faltando informações importantes, vale a pena colocar comentários do tipo "*Você poderia editar a sua pergunta para adicionar o conteúdo da função `x`? Pois sem ela, não dá para saber o que há de errado na função `y`*". E observe que isso é diferente de "*Você poderia dizer qual é o conteúdo da função `x`?"*, pois desta forma estou também orientando o usuário a editar a pergunta e explicando porque isso é importante, a fim de evitar possíveis futuros transtornos. Aqui vai [um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65163/joptionpane-erro-bot%c3%a3o-cancelar/65165#comment133215_65165) onde fiz isso:

> @PauloHenriqueGallo É melhor você editar a pergunta e colocar o código lá. Assim dá para ter certeza que ele está certo. Entretanto, eu já atualizei a minha resposta. Apenas fica a dica que perguntas como a sua normalmente são fechadas pois é difícil se saber o que está acontecendo, uma vez que ela não mostra o código, e isso faz com que a pergunta seja difícil de ser respondida. Então fica a dica para a próxima vez. – Victor Stafusa 21/05 às 3:48

No caso de respostas que não são respostas, também vale orientar. Se o usuário colocou uma outra pergunta como resposta, vale adicionar um comentário dizendo que o melhor é ele fazer uma pergunta específica e linkar a pergunta que ele respondeu e evitar pegar carona na pergunta dos outros. Depois disso, a resposta pode ser deletada. Se a resposta deveria ser um comentário, eu dou um flag para os moderadores e escrevo na descrição "converter em comentário". Isso cria algum trabalho extra para os moderadores, mas o problema de verdade é que não há no momento forma de fazer uma resposta ser convertida automaticamente em comentário ao acumular um determinado número de flags para isso. Se houvesse, os moderadores não precisariam ser incomodados com isso.

E pode parecer estranho a muitos de nós, mas há muitos usuários que não sabem usar o Google. Especialmente quando estão pesquisando por coisas das quais não sabem qual é o nome. Ou quando essa coisa tem um nome que colide com o nome de muitas outras coisas não-relacionadas.

## Downvotes

O downvote é uma arma poderosa. No entanto é poderosa demais, e por causa disso, deve ser usada com muita responsabilidade. Embora o downvote possa ser usado com algo para orientar os usuários, ele deve ser usada de forma cuidadosa se esta for a finalidade, pois quando usado de forma irresponsável acaba sendo entendido como:

- Alguém que nem te conhece e que você não sabe quem é, decidiu que odeia você.
- Você se esforçou tanto para dar o melhor em escrever isso, e alguém simplesmente achou que isso é um total lixo.
- Alguém decidiu não se importar com você.

Se o usuário recebe múltiplos downvotes sem explicação, a mensagem que o usuário pode acabar recebendo é:

- Você não é bem-vindo.
- Todos aqui te odeiam.
- Achamos que isso que você escreveu é um total lixo.
- Ninguém se importa com você.
- Gostaríamos que você fosse se f...

Receber um downvote pode ter o mesmo efeito de receber nota zero naquele trabalho de escola que você se esforçou tanto em fazer, só que tem o detalhe de você não saber quem é que foi que te deu essa nota. O resultado é que grande parte dos usuários vê isso como sendo uma atitude hostil e começa a criar teorias da conspiração malucas em suas cabeças.

A solução novamente é orientar o usuário. Explicar o motivo do downvote já é um bom primeiro passo, pois neste caso o usuário saberá pelo menos com quem falar e poderá tirar algo de bom disso. Entretanto, neste caso, quem deu o downvote tem que estar disposto e preparado a entrar no debate.

Eu em especial, evito dar downvotes. Se forem ver o meu perfil de usuário, verão que são poucos os que já dei. Normalmente os reservo apenas para:

- Usuários que claramente têm más intenções e não apenas simples ingenuidade ou falta de conhecimento.
- Usuários com postura teimosa e cabeça-dura, que querem ser os donos da verdade, e não aceitam quando a sua opinião está errada.
- Usuários que postam perguntas ou respostas com tom desrespeitoso e com a finalidade de desrespeitar.
- Usuários que estão espalhando desinformação, ensinando más práticas de programação ou orientando os demais usuários de forma errada.
- Usuários que propositadamente ignoram, tem descaso ou demonstram oposição a orientações dadas por outros usuários.

E mesmo nestes casos, quando vejo que um comentário já surtirá o efeito desejado, eu prefiro apenas deixar o comentário. No meu ponto de vista, o downvote deve ser usado apenas como um último recurso quando as demais opções falharem, inclusive tentar explicar o que acontece para o usuário.

Para demonstrar sobre os downvotes, aqui vai [um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/94703/1) de um usuário que não soube expressar direito o que queria (embora pelo menos o português seja razoável), não colocou informações importantes na pergunta, teve a pergunta fechada, recebeu downvotes, foi embora e não voltou. Não sei qual foi o motivo pelo qual ele foi embora, pode ou não ter sido os downvotes, pode ser ou não porque a pergunta foi (corretamente) fechada, pode ser que ele tenha resolvido o problema sozinho, pode ser que não quisesse voltar mesmo, ou pode ser algum outro motivo. Entretanto, parecia que no fundo ele teria uma pergunta boa a fazer:

> ### Visualização de tela PHP lenta
>
> Tenho um software feito em php rodando no meu servidor em banco mysql. Em um dos relatorios do software está demorando para exibir a tela. Ela fica carregando e demora mais de 15 minutos. Minha primeira desconfiança foi o banco de dados. Analisei todas as querys, os indices das tabelas e otimizei ao máximo. Porem continuou lenta. Ao analisar o log da aplicação, vejo que todo o processo da tela acaba bem antes de a tela terminar de exibir os dados, ou seja, estou suspeitando da performance do próprio php. Alguém teria uma luz de algo. Alguma configuração do php, cache ou coisa do tipo.
>
> Desde já agradeço a atenção.
>
> [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql)

Aqui vai [outro exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94884/132) de um usuário que se expressou mal, teve a pergunta fechada e negativada, e nunca mais voltou (embora novamente, não sei qual o motivo pelo qual não voltou):

> ### a minha requisição externa não fonciona no celular
>
> criei uma APP , quando uso no computador funciona bem . mas quando crio APK com o phonegap , ele não faz a requisição externa
>
> [phonegap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonegap) [phonegap-builder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonegap-builder)

Eu olho para isso e fico me perguntando se este tipo de postura não está assustando esses usuários. São perguntas de fato horrorosas e muito mal-elaboradas. Mas novamente, será que não estamos a afastar usuários assim?

E também temos o caso clássico de uma resposta correta que recebeu um monte de votos negativos sem nenhum comentário, e que se não fosse o nosso moderador Sergio aparecer para salvá-la, ela teria se perdido: [É preciso ter calma, refletir em caso de dúvida e se não souber não ir com o rebanho](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4407/132)

Mas será que downvotes sem explicação podem mesmo de fato acabar por revoltar e afastar usuários do nosso site? Será que isso já aconteceu? A resposta é **sim** (ou ao menos parece que sim, pois este caso é bem polêmico, controverso e duvidoso). Veja esse link de uma usuária dando ragequit por causa disso: [Peço desculpa a todos, mas quero fazer uma reclamação sobre downvoter?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1916/132) - Notem pelo [perfil dela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/11549/maria), que ela vinha fazendo uma boa contribuição ao site, mas que depois desse incidente (03/09/2014), foi embora e não mais voltou (entretanto, novamente, esse caso é duvidoso).

Comment: Este é o ponto, creio que os veteranos estão se esquecendo do que passaram pra chagar ate aqui, e aplicando simplesmente o rigor dos recursos. "Se tem o recuso, porque você não esta usando!?, 'downvote'."

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, então, o TL;DR é esse "downvote é muito poderoso e só deve ser usado com responsabilidade"? Não entendo o que o homem aranha tem a ver com controle de qualidade...

Comment: Victor, será que pode dar uns exemplos a respeito do *nosso*  [pt.so]? Só mostra reclamações à respeito do SOen e, como sabemos, [Aqui NÃO É o stacoverflow.com](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1/201)...

Comment: @brasofilo Bem, a ideia é não repetir os erros do nosso irmão em inglês, e muita coisa que aconteceu com eles pode ocorrer conosco, por isso coloquei esses links aí que são bem conhecidos e já foram debatidos algumas vezes no metão e no meta do SOen, mas que acredito poucos aqui no SOpt conhecem. Entretanto, vou procurar uns casos aonde coisas assim aconteceram aqui no SOpt, uma vez que já vi esses problemas por aqui também (felizmente em intensidade bem menor que no SOen).

Comment: @brasofilo Aqui vai um caso: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4407/132 - Se não fosse o Sergio intervir e levar isso para o meta, uma boa resposta correta teria se perdido tendo uma forte pontuação negativa. Há outros casos por aí - estou a procura.

Comment: @brasofilo Resposta editada

Comment: @VictorStafusa pra você ver como é fácil especular sobre o porque das pessoas fazerem algo e errar, no último parágrafo você citou um usuário bem problemático que tem um histórico bem ruim no site e não foi por causa de *downvote* que abandonou o site. Na verdade não abandonou. Esta é apenas uma das diversas contas que vai criando, arrumando confusão e abandonando. Esse você errou. Será que os outro não errou também?  Não dá para especular essas coisas. Tem milhares de usuários que abandonaram o site e só receberam ups.

Comment: @bigown Olhando as perguntas e respostas dela, me parece que estava contribuindo bem. Entretanto fiquei curioso, o que faz você concluir que o histórico era bem ruim? Você está dizendo que ela era sockpuppet? E se usuários problemáticos são os que arrumam confusão, então você é o mais problemático de todos (SUpt) e eu também seria muito problemático pelo mesmo motivo. Talvez eu tenha errado, não queria sair apontando para casos específicos e apenas dar uma noção geral do que vejo, mas o brasofilo pediu para eu apontar esses casos específicos.

Comment: É outro tipo de confusão e problema. É caso crônico de quem não consegue viver junto com outras pessoas. O caso até é bem conhecido. Mas parece que não pode falar muito sobre ele. A pessoa vive voltando com conta nova ou trocando nome. Porque acha que é algo pessoal, quando na verdade o problema é a atitude que nunca muda em todas as contas. Ele apaga as confusões que arruma, mas tem rastros. Talvez o brasofilo esteja justamente falando que tudo nesta página é especulação. Tem ocorrido muito ultimamente aqui. Por isso eu nem entro nessas discussões.

Comment: @bigown Agora fiquei em dúvida. Sei que eu devo editar a resposta neste último parágrafo, mas não sei o que eu colocaria no lugar. Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2):

Sociologicamente, creio que os sites Stack Exchange constituem *comunidades*, não *sociedades*, mas como o [TL;DR](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1641/respostas-que-come%C3%A7am-com-tldr-ou-tddr) da pergunta parece ser "grandes poderes -> cuidado com o *downvote*", vou comentar sobre isso.

### Votar, o poder hiper-valorizado

> "Com grandes poderes vem grandes responsabilidades"

Excelente frase de efeito e rapidamente associada com *downvotes* pelo AP e, ao mesmo tempo, pode ser que reflita um sentimento mais extenso da comunidade SOpt.

Mas se formos falar de poderes (ou privilégios), temos que olhar [as regras do jogo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) que estamos jogando para adquiri-los via pontos de reputação: **votar positivo** <sup>[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IK4I.png)</sup> é *o poder mais minúsculo* (o mais abusado?). Depois, *relativamente bem pequeno*, vem **votar negativo** <sup>[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IK4I.png)</sup>.

Lá encima, muitos pontos acima, vem **editar** <sup>[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IK4I.png)</sup> perguntas e respostas livremente. Acho que este é um poder crucial e volto nele ao final.

Votar para **fechar e reabrir** <sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IK4I.png)</sup> já é quase como ter as chaves da casa, aqui sim estamos falando de "grandes responsabilidades". **Depois de 10 mil** <sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IK4I.png)</sup> (e vinte), os poderes são para quem gosta de ajudar na manutenção do site através de relatórios exclusivos; se não, o mais interessante (divertido!) é poder ver os posts excluídos.

[image]

---

## Editar, o poder esquecido

Pois é...
***Já vi mais de uma vez*** usuários com mais de dois mil pontos de reputação e com ou sem diamantes participarem em discussões nos comentários e no Meta à respeito de perguntas problemáticas, darem respostas fantásticas a essa mesma pergunta, **e** não terem o bom-senso/disposição de editar a pergunta também.

Ficamos com aquele -3 encima de uma pergunta meio básica, meio inexperiente, meio tosca, quando uma edição rigorosa no título, na descrição, no código, nas tags, melhoraria a coisa em {vários} porcentos...
Incluindo aquele comentário do AP que poderia ter sido incorporado na pergunta para esclarecê-la, que fica lá, escondido abaixo do corpo da pergunta num mar de outros comentários.

Acho que *dá para salvar várias perguntas de serem negativadas **fazendo edições relevantes** no melhor [espirito Wiki](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) deste site*.
O poder de converter um título como `[php] função error-code, Ajuda!`
em `Resumo básico do meu problema`, infelizmente, é infra-valorado...

Comment: Editar é, disparada e indiscutivelmente, o maior poder do site. Seja por ser o que requer o maior bom senso, compreensão e disposição quanto por ser o mais benéfico para a comunidade. Vejo todos os outros privilégios (anteriores ou posteriores) como paliativos, que dependem de um comprometimento menor que a edição e que, assim, apresentam um benefício menos profundo. Editar é o caminho, a luz e a vida.

Comment: Concordo editar poderia resolver muitos problemas de downvote, mas nem sempre da pra [saber o que o AP quer](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98468/o-que-faz-esse-c%C3%B3digo#comment-200174), assim não tem como editar. Pessoalmente não gosto de editar prefiro [deixar comentários ao AP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97466/problema-com-express%C3%A3o-regular/97495#97495) - quem tem mais de 10k vai ver - solicitando para aletrar determinado trecho. Penso que o conteúdo é de responsabilidade no AP ou AR é ele quem deve disser se minha edição - "comentário" - é relevante e se adequá.

Comment: Edições envolvem interpretação. Dependendo como for minha edição eu posso mudar o contexto de interpretação, o que é ruim. Creio que o AP deve tentar passar seu pensamento, para não tirar conclusões precipitadas, editando algo erronia mente. E esto - de meu ponto de vista - deve vir através de comentários.

Comment: Ao meu ver **Downvote** > **Editar**, pois meche mais com o psicológico da pessoa, pois é puramente negativo; uma edição não, pode ser interpretado apenas como uma melhoria uma ajuda para a questão. E a edição que você comenta é a permanente com 2k, pois usuário com 1 de pontuação ja podem editar, mas então como sugestão e não efetivo, assim ja se doutrina o usuário a utilizar a ferramenta corretamente, pois o que ele edita mal, não é aceito.

Comment: @Guilherme, o voto é para determinar a qualidade do post e não da pessoa, se o "psicológico da pessoa" se sente diminuido/ofendido, não é problema meu. O [exemplo que oferece](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98468/o-que-faz-esse-código) tem 2 comentários do AP explicando o que quer e que *deviam* ser passados pra dentro da pergunta.